# Настройки nginx для TOR

Tags: nginx, tor

Довольно давно один из сайтов имеет зеркало в TOR.
Но появилась небольшая проблема, используется модуль ngx_http_limit_conn_module. 
Ограничивающий количество запросов с 1 ip адреса. 
Все пользователи использующие TOR зеркало, имеют ip 127.0.0.1 
Зеркалом становится практически не возможно пользоваться.

Как обойти ограничение? Возможно сделать как-то условие для модуля?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи `geo` и `map` составить *whitelist*. Например, как-то так:

```
http {
    # some http-section config here
    geo $whitelist {
       default 0;
       # CIDR in the list below are not limited
       1.2.3.0/24 1;
       9.10.11.12/32 1;
       127.0.0.1/32 1;
    }

    map $whitelist $limit {
        0     $binary_remote_addr;
        1     "";
    }

    # The directives below limit concurrent connections from a 
    # non-whitelisted IP address to five

    limit_conn_zone      $limit    zone=connlimit:10m;

    limit_conn           connlimit 5;
    limit_conn_log_level warn;   # logging level when threshold exceeded
    limit_conn_status    503;    # the error code to return

    # The code below limits the number requests from a non-whitelisted IP
    # to one every two seconds with up to 3 requests per IP delayed 
    # until the average time between responses reaches the threshold. 
    # Further requests over and above this limit will result 
    # in an immediate 503 error.

    limit_req_zone       $limit   zone=one:10m  rate=30r/m;

    limit_req            zone=one burst=3;
    limit_req_log_level  warn;
    limit_req_status     503;

    # other http-section config here
}
```

Подробнее у коллег [тут](https://serverfault.com/questions/177461/how-to-rate-limit-in-nginx-but-including-excluding-certain-ip-addresses) и в манах nginx [geo](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html), [map](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html).